# Wait until all threads are started before run them

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

i'd like to do the same thing of this part of script, but possibly in a different way. Is it possible? This script waits that all threads are ready and started and then run the while True of urllib.request... Since I don't want to copy-paste this method, is there a different way to do it?

```
import threading, urllib.request

class request(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while nload:
            time.sleep(1)
        while True:
            urllib.request.urlopen("www.google.it")

nload = 1

for x in range(800):
    request().start()
    time.sleep(0.003)
    print "Thread " + str(x) + " started!"

print "The cycle is running..."
nload = 0
while not nload:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to use a [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) object.

```
import threading, urllib.request

go = threading.Event()

class request(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        go.wait()
        while True:
            urllib.request.urlopen("www.google.it")

for x in range(800):
    request().start()
    time.sleep(0.003)
    print "Thread " + str(x) + " started!"

print "The cycle is running..."
go.set()
```

This guarantees that no thread will advance past the `go.wait()` line until `go.set()` is called. It can't ensure that the 800 threads wake up at the exact same moment, since your number of CPU cores, your operating system's scheduler, python's GIL, and probably a lot of other things I don't know about prevent you from having that degree of control.